# How to delete all nested objects referenced to an object?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a model which is set as foreign key in several models. Right now deleting any object from the model throws ProtectedError if it is referenced in any of those model. I want to let user delete the object with all protected objects in a single operation.

I can delete the first layer of protected objects by simply calling

```
....    
except ProtectedError as e
    e.protected_objects.delete()
....
```

But when the `protected_objects` have their own protected objects, the operation fails and throws another second layer `ProtectedError`. What I want to achieve is, deleting all the protected objects undiscriminating in which layer it exists. I am aware that it can be a dangerous operation to perform. But can I achieve this without a complex solution. Thanks in advance.

Source Code, where I am trying to perform the ajax operation:

```
try:
    obj_list = model.objects.filter(pk__in=pk_list)
    log_deletion(request, obj_list, message='Record Deleted')
    obj_list.delete()
    return JsonResponse({'success': True, 'status_message': '{0} record(s) has been deleted successfully.'.format(len(pk_list))})
except ProtectedError as e:
    e.protected_objects.delete()
    return JsonResponse({'success': False, 'status_message': 'This operation cannot be executed. One or more objects are in use.'})
```

Comment: You could use a loop?

Comment: Can you show the `...` explicitly please?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I have added the source code. 
Loop can be a solution but I need to show all the protected objects in all layer related to the objects. would that be possible?

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from logging at each iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you could use a loop:

```
...
except ProtectedError as e:
    obj = e.protected_objects
    while True:
        try:
            obj.delete()
        except ProtectedError as e:
            obj = e.protected_objects
        else:
            break
...
```

To log which layer the errors happen in, you can add a counter:

```
from itertools import count

obj_list = model.objects.filter(pk__in=pk_list)
for layer in count():
    try:
        log_deletion(request, obj_list, message='Record Deleted in layer {}'.format(layer))
        obj_list.delete()
    except ProtectedError as e:
        obj_list = e.protected_objects
    else:
        if layer == 0:
            return JsonResponse({'success': True, 'status_message': '{0} record(s) has been deleted successfully.'.format(len(pk_list))})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'success': False, 'status_message': 'This operation cannot be executed. One or more objects are in use.'})
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you might not want to use `on_delete=models.PROTECT` on the definition of the foreign keys. Have you considered [changing the on delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) to use `CASCADE` instead? If you use cascade, you won't need to iterate over the dependencies to delete them first.

Rather than:

```
class OtherModel(models.Model):
    link = models.ForeignKey("Link", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

You could define the model like:

```
class OtherModel(models.Model):
    link = models.ForeignKey("Link", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

When deleting models from the admin that use `CASCADE` an intermediate page will be shown that lists all the dependent objects that will also be deleted.

Comment: For now, we are use models.PROTECT as we need to let user know what related objects we are deleting and this process go through a prompt for confirmation.